# Running Track, painted material, right way to do it?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm doing a running track with painted lanes and numbers. It it easy to do base material itself (eg. sand or black rubber) using the principled shader and correct material setup and I have also png-texture with orange lanes with white stripes and numbers + alpha channel to broke uniform color. 
The problem is how to mix them together to make a realistic outcome?

I try to add the lane texture to "Subsurface Color" input but I'm not sure if this is the right way.

I would like to get something like this:

[image: Running track]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Final:

You can make this with procedural texture mixed by alpha image (lines/numbers).

[image: final]

### Node overview:

1. Base procedural textures. **Voronoi** for main bumps and **Noise** to make it less uniform.
2. **Color Ramps** for fine control over textures intensity.
3. Mixed base textures and **Color Ramp** for **Base Color** input.
4. **Brightness/Contrast** to tweak **Roughness**.
5. **Bump** node to feed **Normal** inputs.
6. **Image Texture** with only white shapes and transparent background mixed with base textures. **Color Ramp** controls how much wear there is on shapes (how much orange color is visible trough them, based on **Voronoi** texture).

[image: nodes]

Comment: Thanks for Your material - great one! I can't make it work in later Blender versions. Can You please update materials for Blender 2.83+ ?